# Are there any naming conventions for characters in Star Wars?

Tags: star-wars

*Full disclosure: I have only seen the movies, and certainly the prequels only once; this is for a project.*

Is there a naming convention for any of the Star Wars characters?  Names like Luke & Leia are pretty white bread, while Obi-Wan Kenobi, etc.  I understand that this is a very large galaxy, so a lot will not be explained, but **are there any references in or out of the movies for characters' names?** Even if there are any in 'the real world,' from the creators.

Comment: I won't bother answerig, but Luceno's interviews touched on this and he seemed to indicate that - aside from special names insisted on by LSG like "Sheev", he could make up names any way he wanted.

Comment: Darth <something a bit evil>

Comment: Vader and Sidious are both words if you add "in-" to the beginning.  "Invader".  "Insidious".

Comment: @WadCheber Darth Continent, Darth Tractable, and Darth Destructible didn't make the cut.

Comment: @wadcheber Darth Conceivable was dropped after the threat of legal action from the makers of The Princess Bride

Comment: Relevant: [How to Find Your Star Wars Name](http://sharksplode.com/comic/how-to-find-your-star-wars-name/)

Comment: It seems to be "Naughty word (+/- minor changes)":
Plague - Plagueis, Insidious - Sidious, Invader - Vader, Snake - Snoke, Tyrant - Tyranus, Maul - Maul. Even the EU is this way, e.g. Rampage - Ramage, Venomous - Venamis, Congac - Cognus??! I'd love to see what goes on behind the scenes when a master names his padawan.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's what George Lucas said about *Star Wars* names.

> "Basically, I developed the names for the characters phonetically,'' Mr. Lucas said. ''I obviously wanted to telegraph a bit of the character in the name. The names needed to sound unusual but not spacey. I wanted to stay away from the kind of science fiction names like Zenon and Zorba. They had to sound indigenous and have consistency between their names and their culture."

[This article](http://www.nytimes.com/1997/01/26/movies/the-names-came-from-earth.html) also talks about where some specific character names came from.

> "I have a little book and I just write names all day long,” he explained. “You just riff on that idea and you end up with a bunch of names. I have hundreds and hundreds, even thousands of names."

([Source](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2012/01/23/oprahs-next-chapter-george-lucas-names-star-wars-video_n_1222978.html))